# Arrangements with the following conditions

Tags: algorithm, math, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

Given a matrix AxB with comprising of integers >=0. The sum of each column of the matrix should be non decreasing on moving from left to right. Also the sum of B<sup>th</sup> column (last column) is less than or equal to A.

Find the number of distinct matrices of such type for a given A and B.

I tried to solve it using recursion and memoization as follows-

The function solve() is-

```
ll solve(ll i,ll curlevel)
{
 if(dp[i][curlevel]!=-1)
    return dp[i][curlevel];
 if(i<0)
    return dp[i][curlevel]=0;
 if(curlevel==B)
    return dp[i][curlevel]=test(i,c);
 if(curlevel>B)
    return dp[i][curlevel]=0;
 ll ans=0;
 for(ll k=i;k>=0;k--)
 {
     ans+= test(i,A)* solve(k, curlevel+1);
 }
 return dp[i][curlevel]=ans;
}
```

The function test is defined as follows-
(It calculates the no of ways a sum ='sum' can occur as a sum of distinct non-negative numbers='places')

```
ll test(ll sum,ll places)
{
 if(mem[sum][places] != -1)
    return mem[sum][places];
 if(sum==0)
    return mem[sum][places]=1;
 if(places==0)
    return mem[sum][places]=0;
 ll val=0;
 for(ll i=0;i<=sum;i++)
 {
    val+=test(sum-i,places-1);
 }
 return mem[sum][places]=val;
}
```

This method however is too slow.

**Is there a faster way to do this?(Maybe a better combinatorics approach)**

Comment: This question makes no sense. If A=10 (there are 10 rows), how can you have a column containing only non-negative numbers that sum to 10 or less, unless every value of the column is 1?

Comment: @tylerdurden- 0's can also be used.We can for example have a column with 1 '10' and rest zeros.

Comment: I suspect this is related to a contest http://www.codechef.com/JUNE15/problems/STDYTAB

Answer (score 0):

You have to precalculate Partitions array - numbers of integer partitions of A into A non-negative parts (including zeros) and taking part order into account (i.e. counting both 0 0 1 and 0 1 0 etc).

**Edit:**
`Partitions(k) = C(A + k - 1, A - 1)`
Example for A = 4
`Partitions[4] = C(7,3)=7!/(4!3!)=35`
whole array:
`Partitions  = {1,4,10,20,35}`
To calculate Partitions, use table - rotated Pascal triangle

```
1  1  1  1  1 
1  2  3  4  5  //sum of 1st row upto ith element
1  3  6  10 15  //sum of 2st row
1  4  10 20 35   //sum of upper row
```

for A = 1000 you need about 1000*sizeof(int64) memory (one or two rows) and about 10^6 modulo additions. If you need to make calculations for many A values, just store the whole table (8 MBytes)

Then use this formula: //**corrected**

```
S(columns, minsum) = Partitions[k] * Sum[k=minsum..A]{ S(columns - 1, k) }
S(1,k) = Partitions[k]
Result = Sum[k=0..A] { S[B,k] }
```

Comment: How do i calculate the partitions array efficiently? Also precalculation will be required for every value of A & B ,right?

Comment: Precalculattion is needed for every A, but doesn't depend on B. It is not necessary to calc it very effectively, simple recursion is enough.

Comment: PreCalculating the partitions is still very slow for A,B=1000. I'm Using the recursion partition(n,k)=partition(n-1,k)+partition(n,k-1) with memoization.

Comment: Is there any way to speed up the initial recursion that uses partitions ?

Comment: for A=1000 numbers might be enormous large. Are you using long arithmetics?

Comment: I'm taking modulo 1000000000(Not prime)

Comment: The problem is that even the recursion alone (function S()) with memoization is too slow, as a test i didn't precompute partitions[] and just multiplied with k instead , just to test the speed. For A=1000,B=1000 it takes 5-6 sec which is too slow.For A=2000 , B=2000 it takes minutes :-(

Comment: Fill 2D table with bottom-up dynamic programming. 0.7 seconds for A,B=2000 (85% of time taken by modulus operation)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the last cell of the last column, if that cell has the value A, then all the other cells in the last column must be 0, so in that case the last column has 1 possible arrangement.

If the last cell has the value A-1, then the cell next to it in the same column can be 0 or 1, so there is one arrangement in which the last column sums to A-1 and A-1 arrangements in which the column sums to A.

In general, the recursive function is:

```
NumberOfArrangementsOfColumn( cells_remaining, value_remaining ){
    if( value_remaining == 0 ) return 1;
    if( cells_remaining == 1 ) return value_remaining + 1;
    int total = 0;
    for( int sub_value = 1; sub_value <= value_remaining; sub_value++ ){
        total += 
          NumberOfArrangementsOfColumn( cells_remaining - 1, sub_value );
    }
    return total;
}
```

This function will determine the number of arrangements for the last column. You then need to create another recursive function for computing each of the remaining columns starting with the next to last column etc. for each possible value.